# Conda 22.9.0 cannot install packages that can be installed with previous versions

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am trying to install some packages (nccl2.4) with conda, and while this was working perfectly using the conda-forge channel with conda 4.6.14, now it does not find it anymore when using conda 22.9.0:

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- nccl=2.4
  Current channels:
- https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/win-64
- https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
  To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
  looking for, navigate to
  https://anaconda.org
  and use the search bar at the top of the page.

On anaconda.org, I can see that the package exists. What could be wrong? Is this related to the new conda version?

Comment: The narrative here - that updating broke things - doesn't cohere. The error message shows a **win-64** platform. That package has never been available for Windows. So, this should never have worked - or else the old version was on WSL, and now you installed a Windows instead?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I actually omitted some important information in the first message, my apologies. The previous version was installed in a linux cluster; what I am trying to do now is to install in WSL2 for windows10... I may have overseen the fact that the package may not be working for WSL, do you think that is the case? Thanks in advance

Comment: AFAIK, one must install a Linux version of Conda in WSL, not a Windows version.